# Using Join to parse out duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a bit of a problem here with this statement below using tables:

```
[Users] Name,Email,Subscribed 
[Email] Name,Email,Subscribed
```

Basically what needs to be accomplished is all the Subscribed Users in the `Users` table need to be checked against the users in the `Email` table to see if they exist in the table or not, and only return the users in the `Users` table which are not found in the Email table.

Here is the statement I've used, but it returns millions of rows and takes forever, and it is returning every email address in the Email table, I don't think this is the best way to approach this issue because it is not returning accurate data.  Any thoughts?

```
SELECT Distinct c.Name,c.Email from Users c 
INNER JOIN Email e on c.Email <> e.Email
WHERE c.Subscribed=1
```

Comment: Is that first WHERE in your question supposed to be an "ON"?  I don't even think that query would compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
   SELECT c.Name,c.Email 
   FROM Users c  LEFT JOIN Email e ON (c.email=e.email)
   WHERE (e.email is null) and (c.subscribed=1)
```

The INNER JOIN in your query with no ON clause is why you are getting wacky results.

Answer (score 0):

change the <> to =

You are doing an join on non-equality so that is why your result size is exploding.

On a side note - check into foreign keys going forward - they make this type of cross table referential integrity a non-issue.

UPDATE - if you want results in one table that are not in the other do:

```
select * from table1 where email not in (select distinct email from table2);
```

This will give you all the records in table1 that don't match an email in table 2.

HTH

Comment: If i do = instead, it only returns the users which exist in both tables, instead of returning the difference of users not found in the Email table.

Comment: Actually, the OP is doesn't even have a criteria in the join expression so it isn't a join on equality or non-equality. The whole approach is flawed. Needs to be rewritten as an outer join as shown in my answer.

Comment: Your solution worked also, and easier to understand, but the best answerers parses faster. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `distinct` is unneeded in a `IN (SELECT ...)` subquery

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a `LEFT JOIN` to accomplish this:

```
SELECT Distinct u.Name, u.Email
FROM Users AS u 
LEFT JOIN Email AS e ON u.Email = e.Email
WHERE e.Email IS NULL
   AND u.Subscribed = 1
```

Graphical explanation of [JOINS](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) may be helpful

I strongly recommend using [Foreign Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177463.aspx) to maintain referential integrity.